# Powermail country list

Tags: typo3, powermail

The country list of powermail is not helpful - countries start with prefixes like "Republic of..." or "Bundesrepublik", which makes it difficult to select a country from the large list. 
Is there a way to use my own country list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the partial of the country field (see https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Resources/Private/Partials/Form/Field/Country.html) leads to the viewhelper:

```
{vh:Form.Countries(key:'isoCodeA3',value:'officialNameLocal',sortbyField:'isoCodeA3',sorting:'asc')}
```

If you don't want "officalNameLocal" just use a different field like "isoCodeA3" or anything else

Comment: Thank you! value:'shortNameLocal' did what I want.